# Overriding !important CSS on amp-user-notification elements

Tags: css, amp-html

I'm implementing [an *amp-user-notification* element](https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/components/amp-user-notification/?format=websites) on an AMP-compliant page. My use case is slightly different than its recommendation: rather than a cookie dismissal prompt, I'm attempting to use it for a dismissible banner notification.

The element itself works as expected, including the use of a button to dismiss the notification. However, I want to adjust the layout so that it's static on the page, rather than a fixed-position element.

While I can adjust some CSS properties, `position: fixed` is added to the `amp-user-notification` element with `!important` declared on Google's end, and since [AMP doesn't support the use of `!important`](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/develop/style_and_layout/style_pages/) in my own custom CSS, I'm unsure of how to adjust this.

Is there a way to use *amp-user-notification* while not making the element sticky?

Comment: You can override the `!important` flag with a specificity selector. Would need to see an example of the current behavior to recommend one though.

Comment: Does amp-lightbox would do the job ? https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-lightbox/?format=websites

Comment: @Dimitri Unfortunately, amp-lightbox is also a forcibly fixed-position element.

Comment: @ChrisW. A link to my development site: http://dev.bridgemi.com/michigan-government/heres-how-michigan-should-spend-bloombergs-10-million-fight-opioids?amp

The element in question is the "The nation's eyes..." box.

Comment: I've not had a chance to use amp before but it seems anything you do to override their stuff is a no-no so I may not be the best to lend suggestion on this one being rather ignorant on the topic matter :D